# Reduction of potassium ion and hydrogen ion

Tags: electrochemistry, electrons

I am studying a galvanic cell, and the cathode uses potassium hydroxide as its electrolyte. I am getting confused as to what gets reduced when electrons come from the anode.

I believe it would be the hydrogen ions (because the solvent is water) as potassium ion would never want to accept an electron (because it has a configuration of a noble gas as an ion and is therefore very stable). However, the pH of the solution would be very basic because KOH is the electrolyte; thus, the reduction potential value of hydrogen ion should also decrease.

Can someone please tell me what the right answer is?

Comment: What are the electrodes made of?

Comment: aluminum is the anode and platinum is the cathode electrode

Comment: Platinum is generally inert, so I would check half reactions involving aluminum...

Comment: no platinum is the electrode that will be in the KOH electrolyte.

Comment: Yes, but the platinum is just there to conduct. It doesn't actually do anything chemistry.

Comment: ya, so i was asking if the hydrogen ion gets reduced or the potassium ion?

Comment: Check the reduction potentials...

Comment: based on what I described in the question can you tel me if I am right when I say that it will be hydrogen than potassium even with the higher pH

Comment: You're not going to make metallic potassium in water...

Comment: but potassium would never want to gain an electron. It has a configuration of noble gas when it is an ion.

Comment: You're adding energy to the system. If it weren't in water, you _can_ add an electron. Indeed, the industrial production of potassium is achieved by [electrolysis of molten $\ce{KCl}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium#Commercial_production).

Comment: wait I am very confused with your comment above. I am asking if I have a cell that has an anode electrode of aluminum giving 3 electrons to the platinum electrode, i think hydrogen would be more likely to "absorb/accept" these electrons (even at a higher pH when there are not so many H+ ions) than K+. Now, my solvent is water so it could be that OH- could be absorbing the electrons. I just want to know what is most likely: H+ accepting the electrons or OH- or K+.

Comment: I'm trying not to outright give you the answer per homework policy since you seem to be moving in the right direction. Adding an electron to potassium ion is highly disfavored (not impossible). Adding an electron to hydroxide isn't great. I think you've already got the correct answer above?

Comment: but I am getting a little confused in that because this reaction is so basic, there won't be enough hydrogen ions to be reduced, so what about those extra electrons that exist at the double layer? Will that react with OH-? Sorry if I am being too repetitive

Comment: Ah... I see your issue. Even at pH 14, there is still a significant amount of hydronium. And proton transfer in water is lightning fast, so as you consume the hydrogen ions via reduction, you'll get more because the equilibrium is fast. Now, at some point, it will be disfavored, but you'd need to use the Nernst equation to figure out if that's the case.

Comment: can you please show me how you can use the Nernst equation to do that?

Comment: I'm on my phone, so now is not the best time. Check wikipedia first... That might enough to help you figure it out.